# Python - How can I make n by n data to matrix using python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I need to make matrix (or array) from n by n data
I have data like this

```py
type a | type b  
　　 1 | 1  
　　 1 | 2  
　　 1 | 3  
　　 2 | 1  
　　 2 | 4  
　　 3 | 1  
　　 4 | 2
```

and I want to make like this:

```py
a/b | 1　 2　 3　 4  
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ  
　1 | 1　 1　 1　 0  
　2 | 1　 0　 0　 1   
　3 | 1　 0　 0　 0  
　4 | 0　 1　 0　 0
```

Isn't there anything in python library? (pandas.. etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly simple. The table you have just denotes to the indices of a 2-dim array in Python. For the sake of simplicity, you can use NumPy Arrays:

```py
import numpy as np


data = np.array([
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 1],
    [4, 2]
]) - 1  # Index starts at 0
n = 4

matrix = np.zeros((n, n))

#      -a index-  -b index-
matrix[data[:,0], data[:,1]] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your data in a pandas dataframe you can use crosstab: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

This will give you the frequency table that you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1,1,1,2,2,3,4], 'col2': [1,2,3,1,2,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: 
                pd.Series(x.values)).unstack().reset_index()
df = df.fillna(0)
df.columns = ['col1','1','2','3']
df[df[['1','2','3']] != 0] = 1
df
```

The below is another solution using text CountVectorizer from sklearn package, and it works for any types of data:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

d = {'col1': [1,1,1,2,2,3,4], 'col2': [1,2,3,1,2,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(str)

df = df.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()

corpus = list(df['col2'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=corpus, columns=['cols'])
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=['1','2','3','4'], token_pattern=r"(? 
                                                           u)\b\w+\b")
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['cols'].values)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df.index = df.columns
df
```

[image]